# VBA to handle error

Tags: vba

I want to handle error in VBA in IF condition For my following code the problem is that when i write **On error resume Next** it is handling error but continue with next statement in that is condition only,
But i want to skip to next for loop

My Code:-

```
On Error GoTo 0
On Error Resume Next
For intRow = 2 To intLastRow

  If selenium.getText("//form[@id='searchForm']/div[3]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]") = DOS Then

    clmn = selenium.getText("//form[@id='searchForm']/div[3]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]")
    selenium.findElementByLinkText(clmn).Click
    FileNo = FileNo + 1
    Worksheets("Input").Cells(intRow, 9).Value = FileNo

  End If

Next intRow
```

Answer (score 1):

You can tell it to jump to a maker on error:

```
On Error GoTo errFound
For intRow = 2 To intLastRow
    If selenium.GetText("//form[@id='searchForm']/div[3]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]") = DOS Then
        clmn = selenium.GetText("//form[@id='searchForm']/div[3]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]")
        selenium.findElementByLinkText(clmn).Click
        FileNo = FileNo + 1
        Worksheets("Input").Cells(intRow, 9).Value = FileNo
    End If
errFound:
Next intRow
```

However, I would put some if statements in there to try and handle errors rather than just jumping over them,